# Where can I ask about television and its business aspect?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm interested in how television works with its shows. Specifically, I'd like to know what makes a channel decide whether to air a certain show (tv series) or not.

Earlier I read somewhere that tv channels don't earn any money from airing tv series, but rather receive payments from advertisers whose ads are shown inbetween show's (commercial breaks). Better show > bigger audience > more ad views. So I'd like to know more about how money circulates in this business and how it influences different shows' chance to get air time.

Is there a SE site for this kind of question?

Comment: TV stations are not in the business of delivering shows to audiences; they're in the business of delivering audiences to advertisers. The BBC is, of course, an exception. This is well known. What's your actual question?

Comment: Perhaps Movies and TV? Not sure.

Comment: It's kinda two in one. First, I want to know more about who pays whom, and second, why a seemingly popular shows are canceled (Firefly, Futurama, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [Economics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics?referrer=vGJdkR-7X0N9c2qQO4fLxA2) gets launched, that would be a good place to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about that business aspect but you can ask movie or Television question

@  [Movies & TV beta](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).

> Movies & TV Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for movie and tv enthusiasts. It's 100% free, no registration require.

Comment: chances are they'll consider editing that text after my question gets closed :p